# If S contains an anonymous field T, does the method sets of S include promoted methods with receiver *T?

Tags: go

The title of the question is almost quoted from the [golang specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> Given a struct type S and a type named T, promoted methods are
>   included in the method set of the struct as follows:
>
> - If S contains an anonymous field T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S also includes promoted methods with receiver *T.

This is a [go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/mWpCm-jbgp) shows that The method `inc()` is promoted.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// just an int wrapper
type integer struct {
    i int
}

func (self *integer) inc() {
    self.i++
}

type counter struct {
    integer
}

func main() {
    c := counter{}

    c.inc()
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No the methods of *T would not be promoted. The specification doesn't explicitly allow it so it isn't allowed. However, there is a reason behind this.

At times you may call a *T method on T. However, there is an implicit reference taken. Methods of *T are not considered part of T's method set.

From the [calls section of the Go specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls):

> If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m()

From the [address operator section of the Go specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a pointer of type *T to x. The operand must be addressable, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the addressability requirement, x may also be a (possibly parenthesized) composite literal.

If a S contains a *T, you don't even need to take its address so the methods can be called. If *S contains a T, you know T is addressable because T is a field selector of a pointer indirected struct. For S containing T, this cannot be guaranteed.

---

**UPDATE: why does that code work?**

Remember that *S contains the method set of *T. Also, as I quoted before:

> If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m()

Put the two together and you have your answer. Counter is addressable and &counter contains the method set of *T. Therefore, counter.Inc() is shorthand for (&counter).Inc().